# The speed of a boat is 5Km/h in still water. It crosses a river of width 1km along the shortest path in 15 minutes.

Tags: kinematics

> Velocity of the river is?

Since it covers 1km in 15 mins, the relative velocity of the boat with respect to the river will be 
$$\frac 14 V_{br}=1$$
$$V_{br}=4km/h$$
So $$V_b=V_{br} + V_r$$
$$V_r=1km/h$$
The right answer is 3km/h, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The flowing water will give lateral movement to the boat. Think of Pythagoras. Your initial calculation $V_{br}$ will reveal the velocity of water. The equality $V_b = V_{br} + V_r$ is equality of vectors.

Comment: You need to take into account, that velocities are vectors! In this case, it is sufficient to take them as 2-dimensional vectors. The Velocity is the absolute value of the velocity vector. Therefore: $v_b = \sqrt{v_{br} ^2 + v_r ^2}$. Given $v_{br}=4$ and $v_b = 5$, you find $v_r=3$. (recall: $3^2+4^2=5^2$). Try to work out the details of the addition (what are the directions of the velocities!)

Comment: Yeah, thought that, but since the angles weren’t given, I wasn’t sure about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to go along the shortest path is by tilting the boat against the river current. A good picture helps:
[image]

You're given $V_{BW} = 5kmph$ and $V_{BS} = 1km ~in~15min$ .
You can find $V_{WS}$

Answer (score 5):

You should use the equation

$$V_b^2=V_{br}^2+ V_r^2$$

instead of

$$V_b=V_{br} + V_r$$

because the three velocity vectors are not in the same direction. Rather, they form a right triangle.

Then, you get

$$V_r = \sqrt{ V_b^2 - V_{br}^2}  = \sqrt{ 5^2 - 4^2}= 3 \text{km/h}$$